# Tweepy Api Python Response, need help decoding the response

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I trust all is well with you and yours. Thank you for taking a moment to read through this and I apologize if this is a repeat (if it is point me to the right spot and I will read through that!)

I am trying to hit the twitter api via tweepy (cause im to new to figure out python and the twitter official api) and return a result in a useable format.

```
import Auth_Codes
import json

twitter_auth_keys = {
    "consumer_key"          : Auth_Codes.consumer_key,
    "consumer_secret"       : Auth_Codes.consumer_secret,
    "access_token"          : Auth_Codes.access_token,
    "access_token_secret"   : Auth_Codes.access_token_secret
}

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
    twitter_auth_keys["consumer_key"],
    twitter_auth_keys["consumer_secret"]
)

auth.set_access_token(
    twitter_auth_keys["access_token"],
    twitter_auth_keys["access_token_secret"]
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

#api.search_tweets(q = "Aztar")

searched_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
                                                    q = "What you want to search",
                                                    lang = 'en',
                                                    result_type = 'recent',
                                                    count = 1)
                   .items(1)]
print(searched_tweets)
print(type(searched_tweets))
```

when this is executed, I get a very large response that I cannot fully post here.
it is also type: <class 'list'>

I hope that added the spoiler button as intended. My issue is that I have tried in several different ways to convert this into an actual json, and I am struggling as every guide I am following online leads me to a dead end (granted I am learning lots!). In node.js, I would normally leverage a map and sort it that way. Is there something similar I can do here? Not all the data is relevant to me.

Thanks in advance, and really sorry about not knowing how to add a spoiler button if it is at all possible.

I have added the following to it:

```
searched_tweets_dict = json.loads(searched_tweets)
print(searched_tweets_dict)
```

and the result is the following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Dropbox\Backup\Github\Python\Mid_Journey\Search.py", line 33, in <module>
    searched_tweets_dict = json.loads(searched_tweets)
  File "C:\Pthyon_3.10\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

Comment: so what happens if you print out `searched_tweets`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EdoAkse, it printed almost what I wanted, though due to the SO form rules, I was unable to paste it. It was answered though!

Comment: For future reference, you can always sanitize data. For example in this case you could replace the text of the tweets with `bla bla bla` or something. Good to hear that Mikaël managed to resolve your question though

Comment: @EdoAkse thanks for the tip! It was a few hundred characters with truncated url's etc. Though, I did try to shorten it to provide an example. I believe next time, I will upload an image. Thank you very much for tasking the time!

Comment: noooooooo. No images for data. Your question as is was really good, don't make future questions worse by using images. See this [excellent article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this specific meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) about why not to use images.

Comment: @EdoAkse copy that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a `Cursor` if you are only requesting one tweet?

And why don't you just use the generator instead of creating that list?

Anyway, the json object is already included in the Tweepy objects (`._json`).

```py
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(
    api.search_tweets, 
    q = "What you want to search", 
    lang = 'en', 
    result_type = 'recent', 
    count = 1
)

for tweet in cursor.items(1):
    print(tweet._json)
```

Comment: Howdy, I intend to snag more than 1, though for the shake of house keeping I reduced it down to one.

And that worked! Perfectly! Now I just need to solve for the next portion! 

Many thanks!

Comment: @NovemberFalls You're welcome! :) If this answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and marking it as the accepted answer to close the question (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more explanations).

Comment: Michael, my apologies though until I have 15 rep, I cannot upvote it. I tried :D going to figure out how to accept it!